# Any way to dict comprehension in dict comprehension in dict comprehension this?

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

I have this piece of code:

```
position = {}
for x in range(imdim[0]-shapesize+1):
  for y in range(imdim[1]-shapesize+1):
    curim = im[x:x+shapesize,y:y+shapesize]
    shapedict = {}
    for shapeid,(shape,contour) in enumerate(zip(shapes,contours)):
      values = {}
      curshape = curim[shape]
      curcontour = curim[contour]
      values['meandiff'] = curshape.mean()-curcontour.mean()
      values['maxmin'] = int(curshape.min())-int(curcontour.max())
      shapedict[shapeid] = values
    position[(x,y)] = shapedict
return position
```

...where im is an image (numpy array), imdim its shape, shapes and contours are list of binary arrays of smaller dimensions (shapesize*shapesize) than im.

It actually works, but I'm wondering if there is a way of writing all of this in a dict comprehension, inception-style. If yes, would it run faster ?

Also, any comment on style or optimizations are welcome !

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/ --> readability counts. If the code works and is readable (I can guess what it's doing), why would you want to make it less readable?

Comment: I thought making comprehensions was noticeably faster than classical for loops. Apparently I was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do, but I did not really test it:

```
position = {
    (x, y): {
        shapeid: {'meandiff': curim[shape].mean() - curim[contour].mean(),
                  'maxmin': int(curim[shape].min()) - int(curim[contour].max())}
        for shapeid,(shape,contour) in enumerate(zip(shapes,contours))
    }
    for (x,y,curim) in ((x, y, im[x:x+shapesize, y:y+shapesize])
            for x in range(imdim[0]-shapesize+1) 
            for y in range(imdim[1]-shapesize+1)
    )
}
```

The tricky part are the temporary variables you define. For `curim` I created an inner generator expression, otherwise you'd have to write that expression four times. You could do the same for `curshape` and `curcontour`, but I don't think it's worth the additional level of nesting.

Whether it's faster: Probably not, certainly not significantly. What's more important, IMHO, is how readable the code is. This of course is a matter of opinion. Personally, I think it's a bit more readable than your original code.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it works.
I'm going to test if it runs faster than my code.